# How-to create 1 million actors in parallel?

Tags: java, scala, akka

This is just an learning example.

I have an actor which holds an list of 1 million ids
(This is just an stripped down example. In real life these actors could represent bank accounts and I would send them "tell" or "broadcast" messages. So I want to keep them all at the same time in memory)

I want this actor to create 1 million child actors (one for each id)

Is there a more parallel way than this code?

```
receive (Msg,..) {

 ids.stream().forEach(
           id -> {
                    context().actorOf(MyActor.props(id));
                }
    );
}
```

Comment: That won't create 1m actors, let akka do its work and define how many actors are necessary to fulfill this work.

Comment: sorry you surely are right but I am too new to akka so I don't see how?

Comment: You don't specify how many actors akka will need, that's the job of akka. You can ay most tell akka how many actor references it will use.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think you mean Akka manages threads and not Actors.

Comment: @Martynas akka manages both threads and actors. It initializes the threads behind the scenes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, calling `actorOf` does indeed create a new instance of an actor (along with returning the `ActorRef` to communicate with that instance). So if you loop a million times and call `actorOf` a million times then you will have a million instances of that actor type within your system. I'm not sure why you are stating otherwise.

Comment: @cmbaxter is right, the comments by Luiggi are a bit misleading. It is you who defines the structure of your actor system i.e. the number of actors and their supervision hierarchy, and it is akka that takes care of how threads are used by those actors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why not to use a `BroadcastRouter` for the children?

```
val children = system.actorOf(Props[ChildrenActor].withRouter(
      BroadcastRouter(nrOfInstances = amountOfChildren)))
```

This is in case you only need to send messages to all the children every single time. In the case you need to send both broadcast and individual messages to the children, you can use a `ConsistentHashingRouter` instead to map the messages with the children ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a collection to a parallel one to make traversing it concurrent:

```scala
scala> (0 to 20).par.foreach(print)
10211345071289151618192061171314
```

Comment: just to make sure. the code is (could) be starting a Thread in an actor. is this ok? so the creating of actors is a thread safe operation?

Comment: @jack an actor is not the same as a thread. Many actors can work on the same thread, and an actor could also be attended by several threads. Akka takes care of this. I highly recommend you to read and review the basic concepts of akka, which is not a thread pool framework.